# ArrayList<CustomClass> to JsonArray

Tags: java, json, gson

```
ArrayList<Custom> ex= new ArrayList<Custom>();
ex = ApproverDao.fetchRequests();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement el = gson.toJsonTree(ex, new TypeToken<List<Custom>>(){}.getType());//Line4
JsonArray ja = el.getAsJsonArray();
```

I'm getting an error here that says
"The method toJsonTree(List, Type) is undefined for the type Gson". Where have I gone wrong?
I have the c2dm.jar in my build path.

Comment: What version of gson are you using? method is marked since 1.4: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Type

Comment: Oh I am using 1.1. Got it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method toJsonTree was added on 1.4 Gson version: [gson-roadmap](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-roadmap)